# Permission denied when using sysctl to change hostname

Tags: 14.04, permissions, hostname

I'm using a container from codeanywhere which is Ubuntu 14.04.

For homework, I have to change the hostname permanently using `sysctl`. Apparently to change it I have to use the command

```
sysctl kernel.hostname=NEW_HOSTNAME
```

but it gives me this

```
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.hostname'
```

Is there a solution? Thanks

Comment: `sysctl` needs root permission (use `sudo`)

Comment: It takes me to a window where I can "change" the hostname, but  i dunno what to do after that, if I exit it doenst change